# Why is the infinite series of 0^n divergent?

Tags: divergent-series, wolfram-alpha, geometric-series

No lie, Wolfram Alpha just told me it is. My input was "sum from 1 to infinity of 0^n" and its output was "By the geometric series test, the series diverges", but without interpreting as a geometric series for a moment the series is clearly 0+0+0+0+... which can't diverge, it is neither approaching infinity or alternating or changing in any way or form. Is Wolfram Alpha wrong?

Comment: It DOES diverge by the test, but Alpha gives you the correct answer of 0 in two different ways.

Comment: @Jed What do you mean that it does diverge by the test? A geometric series $\sum x^n$ is convergent if $|x|<1$, and it does hold that $|0|<1$.

Comment: It does not give the solution as zero instead it defines the partial series, two different things.

Comment: @user4960003 As the absolutely first thing, Wolfram does write "Infinite sum: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 0^n = 0.$" At least it does for me.

Comment: 'By the geometric test, the series diverges' probably Wolfram Alpha tries to evaluate the quotient "$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{0^{n+1}}{0^n}=\frac{0}{0}$"...

Comment: @Eff, yes of course you are correct, but if $|x|<1$ then it "converges" to $\frac{a}{1-x}$ or in this case $\frac{1}{1-0}=1$.  So what can you say it converges to?

Comment: @Jed Yes, that's an interesting point.

Comment: Yes Wolfram Alpha is wrong. It's a very good service, but it's far from perfect (as with computer software packages in general there can be [bugs](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.3270.pdf)). This is likely an error in the implementation of the ratio test. If the limit does not exist (as is the case here) then the test is inconclusive and does not imply that the series diverge.

Comment: btw [the bug also happens](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+x^n+for+n%3D1+to+infty) for the general series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$.

Comment: Conclusion: Wolfram is not reliable. Why students keep using it, I don't know.

Comment: @Jed: The formula for geometric series is for $n$ starting at $n=0$ and in this context $0^0=1$, thus $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 0^n = \frac1{1-0} = 1$ is correct and intuitive.

Comment: @Wauzl that is true if $0^0=1$  :p